# Working locally on HTML Static site source files without .htm file name extensions

Tags: html, filenames, static-site

In (some) cloud based static web sites the headers can be set so that the url www.exmple.com/contact can be served from the file named contact and not contact.htm or contact.html.

As long as the headers claim the file's content is `text/html` the browser renders them as html (as expected)

This is a feature that most non-static web servers do with ease and typically refer to the process as cruftless links.

The cloud setup is all find and dandy however until I want to work on the site's files locally and check anything before uploading to the cloud container. Static sites tend to have a long fuse in the cache and are very unforgiving. Yes you typically do not want to make a lot of changes to a static site however at some point you do have to make some changes nonetheless.

Brackets.io (http://brackets.io) is an editor with a built in web server that is **virtually perfect** for this kind of work.

**One problem however:** It can't serve files without the `.html` extension properly.

The settings do allow for changing file types (I could for example say that a `.horse` file is in fact html and it would believe that) but when I try a directive that says a filename without an extension is to be served as HTML the editor does recognize it as such (e.g. allows me to edit it as html) but the server portion fails to set the headers properly.

This is not necessarily a how do I fix Brackets.io question -- this is a question on how do I solve the "I want to serve static files **locally** without the .html extension from **something** -- what exactly would that **something** be?"

I can't be the only one trying to do this...

*As a work-aorund for now I simply change the file name's extension locally to add the .html, do the work and then change the filename back. (Script to automate that coming up next of course... or maybe strip the extension during upload...)*

Answer (score 1):

You could try placing the page in a directory called "contact" and renaming the page to default, index, or whatever your server assumes for a default document. It isn't the most elegant solution, but it works with the default web server behavior rather than getting creative with something that might cause problems with edge cases.